# Upload new files from local computer to SharePoint online library

Tags: powershell, csom

I have a script that generated a user report to a csv file. Which work properly. I have added a section to upload all the files from the local computer to the SharePoint library. Which also works fine. However, I just want to upload only new file. This is what i have so far. I changed "$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $false" from $true to $false. I guess I am missing a if exist statement. If someone can help me with the syntax to look at the folder and if the same file name already exist, do not upload.

## Upload file

Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder))
{
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $false
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
$Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}

this is the error I am getting.

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "A file with the name Shared Documents/test.csv already exists. It was
last modified by i:0#.f|membership|test on 19 Sep 2018 16:11:46 -0700."
At C:\Scripts\test\test.ps1:68 char:1
+ $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to check file

```
function IsFileExists()
{
try {
$File = $context.web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/LibraryName/file.txt")
$context.Load($File)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
return $True
}
catch {
return $False
}
}

#File chech logic
$FileExists = IsFileExists
if($FileExists) {
#Dont upload file
}
else {
# upload the file
}
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Nothing was uploaded even the new file was created.

Comment: can you your code after implementing the script